# “gamma” tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[gamma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma) is being used for discussing various topics using the letter γ including [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) (a matter of [color-spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-spaces)), the [gamma-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma-function), and the [gamma-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma-distribution), probably among other topics.

I suggest that [gamma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma) is hopelessly ambiguous and should be blacklisted or at least removed.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like nixing [gamma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma) on its own, and instead having [gamma-correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma-correction) and [gamma-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma-distribution) would be better.  There's probably a lot of topics one might talk about regarding color spaces besides gamma correction:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space

Comment: Yes, there is a lot to color spaces besides gamma, but is anyone going to be interested in *gamma only* such that they would care about the gamma tag? Separately: [tag:gamma-distribution] already exists and has 6 questions, so the matching uses of [tag:gamma] are obviously worth fixing; will retag now.

Comment: I have retagged all five gamma-distribution questions and updated my question with the current situation.

Comment: Sounds to me like renaming existing `gamma` to `gamma-correction` and putting a block on the recreation of `gamma` would be ideal.