# Ambiguous tag [Poisson]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I noticed the tag [poisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poisson) is used for several unrelated mathematical concepts, namely the Poisson equation, Poisson distribution and Poisson process (which is related to the distribution).

The tag wiki refers just to the Poisson distribution, but the usage for the Poisson equation is by no means rare.

I suggest to create separate tags [poisson-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poisson-distribution) and [poisson-equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/poisson-equation) and possibly others, if necessary. There is no reason to have a tag for one mathematician's name.

There was a similar question raised for [gamma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gamma), but no decision was established [“gamma” tag is ambiguous or synonymous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251483/gamma-tag-is-ambiguous-or-synonymous?rq=1)

Comment: Wouldn't this tag really only be useful/on topic for Math.SE or Cross Validated?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander I don't know, but people do use it. 165 questions and 3 followers.

Comment: what about the `poisson` d'avril?

Comment: Now *this* is how a tag burnination discussion should be titled. +1, more if I could.

Comment: What was wrong with the old post title? ["Ambiguous tag Poisson"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/288977/revisions) is much clearer than the current `lol ebin meem` nonsense; please don't abuse edits like this.

Comment: @GoBusto: Not a HHGTTG fan I take it?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander: People do write mathematical and statistical software.  Programming is involved in its creation.  I cannot see why Math SE or Cross Validated would be more appropriate venues for all questions involving either the Poisson equation or Poisson distributions.

Comment: I thought from the title this was a scathing rage-quitter post on Meta. That's why I came. What a disappointment to find a burnination.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I have read the books, and understand the "joke", but there's a difference between a punny name that nevertheless conveys a clear meaning and replacing perfectly understandable titles with pop culture references at the expense of clarity.

Comment: @GoBusto: How about now?

Comment: I vote to rollback to 2.  Punny names are all well and good but this one is not appropriate.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, any form of joviality at all should be removed immediately. Let's all pull together to make this site as miserable and unfriendly as possible. I'd add a wink to the end of this comment but that sort of behaviour should also be discouraged and probably punished by death.

Comment: Within random distributions, I'm having a hard time imagining someone who would follow the poisson-distribution tag but not a normal-distribution or  exponential-family tag.  Similarly with PDEs; are there that many users out there would follow a Poisson-Equation tag but shrug their shoulders helplessly at a question tagged Laplace-Equation?  Why aren't [random] and [pde] sufficient here?

Comment: Can we please simply roll back to v2, before the needless title change was made? I'd rather **focus on the actual question** than discuss ["hilarious"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pointless) title edits. "*This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.*"

Comment: Geez, has everyone had their sense of humour surgically removed today?  First this, then [this....](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289058/declined-flags-for-joke-comment-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Not to mention [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289040/turn-off-stackegg). "'Fun', you say? I do not know of this human concept."

Comment: It's not that we hate fun, it's that the "funny" title wasn't fun. Simply referencing a funny book is not enough to make a funny joke.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: The humor comes in the double-substitution Poisson -> poison -> fish.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. It's not really humour though. It's a pun (and I don't see how poison comes into it.. Poisson is French for fish).

Comment: This is fishy...

Comment: @Pekka웃 Good funny titles still describe the topic, for example "I want to delete the [internet]" or at least "Is this tag [note] worthy?". The quote used here dropped the meaning completely. Besides that the title was changed by another user, not the OP, and we shouldn't start editing random posts of other people just to be funny.

Comment: Well, a) it made it easier for me to find as it's now a hot meta post, plus it was mildly amusing so I looked, and b) it does still indicate the topic as it indicates the possibility of [Poisson] going away, though that's only 100% clear after you look, and c) it brightened up my day a little even if it's not "hilarious"

Comment: Meanwhile another question in this tag emerged. It is also tagged [tag:gamma-distribution].