# Turn off StackEgg

Tags: feature-request, stackegg

StackEgg is the lastest effort in gamefying Stack Overflow. 
However short of adding additional rules to adblock, there is no way to turn it off.

The rules for adblock are:

```
||cdn.sstatic.net/stackegg/*
||cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stackegg.js?*
```

Can we please have an <kbd>x</kbd> somewhere in the StackEgg region, so that these of us who want to get some work done whilst having Stack Overflow open in a Windows are not distracted by that ridiculous stack [tamagotchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi)?

Oh and whilst you're at it, why not make it blinking in yellow and purple against a black and white psychedelic spiraling background (and add some distracting sounds as well).

Comment: already demonstrated in the duplicate, but: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2utoD.png

Comment: @MarcGravell SO feels uncharacteristically slow this morning. Do you think this may be related to the egg, or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight we are investigating a performance problem - *possibly* related, but I don't want to pre-empt that

Comment: @MarcGravell as I commented on the dupe, hiding the opt-out mechanism in a "help" menu is really non-obvious - I ended up hiding it with AdBlock as well as I didn't see a way to opt out. Next time, think about either making the opt-out more prominent, or simply post an announcement that describes how to opt out.

Comment: Disabling StackEgg doesn't seem to resolve the slowness opening a question and just trying to read a comment. However this slowness appeared here (Italy) today with this bonus.

Comment: It's gone anyway.

Comment: And performance has returned, for me :-)

Comment: @Cherryade It's gone for me too - as has the leaderboard page, which was available at: http://stackoverflow.com/stackegg/leaderboard

Comment: [`feature-complete`](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582900535122104320) :)

Comment: Dear internet, I am a very serious developer, and hate fun.

Comment: @ChrisBaker: It's not funny, if you are on a slow connection and an important tool is not working because of a not very funny prank. An easier way to disable this annoyance would be fine. If you know only a little bit about UX design, it should be obvious it need's to be possible to disable it without searching for a solution.

Comment: @andreas I am on a connection that tops out at 1.5mb on a good day, no problems loading any pages. I'm sorry, but your claim that a tiny image in the sidebar destroys the entire UX is disingenuous and dramatic. Almost every website on the entire internet has images in the sidebar, it does not render the site unusable. Trust me.... it's funny. Hilarious, at this point.

Comment: @ChrisBaker: Sorry, if I insulted you, but English is not my native language  and maybe I did not state my point as clear, as intended. To clear things up. I do not have a slow connection. I had troubles loading SO two days ago in general. I assume, troubles had been connected to the easter egg. Two days ago I barely could open any pages on SO. Pages opened after about 30 seconds and the connection was never closed. Yesterday opening had been faster, but connections had been still dangling forever. I assume this caused resource bottlenecks on the servers. So UX was completely destroyed. TBC...

Comment: ... As suggestion, It would have been nice to disable the Tamagotchi with one little red cross in the upper right corner, as it's standard in UI design and well known to all users. This is the point I wanted to criticise. On the other hand, I do not know, whether the Tamagotchi and the problems had been related at all.