# Is StackEgg causing me problems, or something else?

Tags: support, stackegg

Earlier this morning, I was incapable of loading any pages on Stack Overflow due to very, very slow loading speeds. That has since disappeared, however I still cannot vote, ask questions, view Edit queues, fetch comments / comment myself, or answer *certain* questions. Upon attempting to do most of these things, I get :

> An error has occurred - please retry your request.

I am on a computer that has WebMarshal enabled, which is blocking me from fetching comments/comments altogether with

> The web site was restricted by the rule 'Analyze Files\Block - Unpacking Error'.

however before today I have never had any issues at any point with the site, and have been active for ~2 weeks. Is this a result of StackEgg, or are there strange happenings taking place with my account?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

From our [VP of Engineering](https://twitter.com/df07/status/582906770034683904):

[image: The _yolk's_ on us.]

```
David: so we DDoSed ourselves with our own april fools' prank?

Core Build: NY-WEB06 / Core (Q&A): Scheduled route failure: stackoverflow.com/

Bosun: 20761 Exceptions in the past 5 m. Apps: Graph, core=20124, Stac
       (Ack Alert)

Marc: @DavidFullerton joke's on us
```

*(image is truncated in a few spots, transcription is of visible text)*

Comment: Had to pull out my phone to ask/comment on this. A sad day of no Stack-Overflowing I guess... *sigh* . Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @DonkeyKong: If you are still having problems, you can [turn off Stack Egg](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289039/1438), which should get you productive again.

Comment: As a result of WebMarshal ( *I think* ), I cannot even find StackEgg anywhere to disable it.

Comment: My finger is hovering over the flag button.  This is after all just a link and not really a useful answer.  Could you please quote the twitter post so everyone, including those trapped behind corporate firewalls and see the answer.

Comment: @JonEricson It's worth noting that despite figuring out how to disable StackEgg, I still cannot vote at all, comment or see comments on *certain* posts, or answer certain questions on my machine with WebMarshal active. This was not the case before today.

Comment: @DonkeyKong: Hmmm... I'm afraid I don't know anything about WebMarshal. If you can configure it to block specific URLs, you might try blocking [the Stack Egg static content and JavaScript](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289040/turn-off-stackegg).

Comment: This amuses me more than it should.

Comment: @SterlingArcher What does exactly?

Comment: @DonkeyKong IANSA, but I think Archer is amused by how the Stack Overflow team DOSAed itself.